# Ajax call on yii dialog box close function fails

Tags: php, jquery, yii, jquery-dialog, zii-widgets

I have this problem with using ajax call on dialog box close function.

Here's my ajax call function:

```
function samplefunction(var1,var2){     

    $.ajax({
        url: "controllerFunction?var1="+var1+"&var2="+var2,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#htmlmessage").html(data.message);
            $("#htmlmsgdialog").dialog("open");
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the dialog box code:

```
<?php 
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
    'id'=>'sampledialogboxname',
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Sample Dialog Box I',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
        'modal'=>true,
        'resizable'=>false,
        'draggable'=>false,
        'position'=>array("middle",30),
        'width'=>650,
        'show'=>'fade',
        'hide'=>'fade',
        'open' => 'js:function(event,ui){
                      //some code here
        }',
        **'close' => 'js:function(event,ui){
                        samplefunction("samplestring1","samplestring2");
                        window.location.href = "'.$sampleurl.'";
        }',**
        'buttons' => array
        (
            array('id' => 'firstback','text'=>'BACK',
                        'click'=> 'js:function(){
                                    samplefunction("samplestring1","samplestring2");
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                    window.location.href = "'.$sampleurl.'";
                        }'),
            array('id' => 'secondback','text'=>'BACK','click'=> 'js:function(){
                                    //some code here
                        }'),
            array('id' => 'thirdback','text'=>'BACK','click'=> 'js:function(){
                                    //some code here
                        }'),
            array('id' => 'fourthback','text'=>'BACK','click'=> 'js:function(){
                                    //some code here
                        }'),
            array('id' => 'firstnext','text'=>'NEXT','click'=> 'js:function(){
                                    //some code here
                        }'),
            array('id' => 'secondnext','text'=>'NEXT','click'=> 'js:function(){
                                    //some code here
                        }'),
            array('id' => 'thirdnext','text'=>'NEXT','click'=> 'js:function(){
                                    //some code here
                        }'),
            array('id' => 'save','text'=>'SAVE','click'=> 'js:function(){
                                    //some code here  
                        }')
        ),
    ),
));?>
```

Here's the controller function:

```
public function actionControllerFunction($var1, $var2)
{
    var_dump($var1, $var2);
    //Do Some Code here

    $result['showdialog'] = true;
    $result['message'] = "Sample Msg.";

    echo json_encode($result);
    exit;
}
```

My Problem is, ajax call always fails even before i enter the controller function.
I checked my parameters it has also the appropriate string to be passed.
I badly need help. Any comments that would help me with this are highly appreciated.
Thanks. (^__^)

Comment: You mean ajax call is not happening.? What is the status of ajax call.?

Comment: I don't see any returned status, just the url is in red in the firebug and no action has been done. (_._)

Comment: You check the reponse of the request in firebug

Comment: i've already tried several ways yet the result is still the same. my other ajax call is magnificently working, it's just this one.

Comment: it didn't throw any response, just the params,headers, post and cookies.

Comment: url in read means an error.Either any internal server error or url not found or request is cancelled.So try error method of ajax to track the error

Comment: Hi. i've tried catching the status of my ajax call.it gives me a zero (0) status.

Answer (score 0):

I think you best bet is to fix the url you are accessing though ajax function :

**In view file**

```
$sampleurl=Yii::app()->createUrl("controllerName/sampleFun");
$ajaxFun=Yii::app()->createUrl("controllerName/controllerFunction");
$ajaxReq = <<<JS
function samplefunction(var1,var2 ,dlg,refreshUrl){     

    $.ajax({
        url: "$ajaxFun&var1="+var1+"&var2="+var2,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#htmlmessage").html(data.message);
            $("#htmlmsgdialog").dialog("open");
        }
    });

    if(dlg!=null ) $(dlg).dialog('close');
    //window.location.href=refreshUrl
}
JS;
```

Note the url : `url: "$ajaxFun&var1="+var1+"&var2="+var2,`

give context controler is `SiteController` its ajax urlshould be sth like:

`site/controllerFunction&var1=abc&var2=def`

complete url will be :

`index.php?r=site/controllerFunction&var1=abc&var2=def`

in your case you have wrongly put

`index.php?r=site/controllerFunction?var1=abc&var2=def`

Note two (?) which will be obviously wrong.

**A Suggestion:**

1. Fix the function by droping the arguments

   `public function actionControllerFunction(){
       //use $_POST array 
        ....
    }`
2. Send the data as post data from ajax method 
    function samplefunction(var1,var2 ,dlg,refreshUrl){

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: "$ajaxFun",
       data:"&var1="+var1+"&var2="+var2",
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data)
       {
           $("#htmlmessage").html(data.message);
           $("#htmlmsgdialog").dialog("open");
       }
   });
   ```

   Note    `url: "$ajaxFun",data:"&var1="+var1+"&var2="+var2",`

Hope this will be helpful [read further](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/46363-multiple-parameters-not-working-with-controller-actions/)